# Dojo Enhanced Grid Cookie Plugin doesn't write generate cookie

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I'm creating a Javascript application that uses a dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid with several plugins including the Cookie plugin. According to all of the documentation and forum posts I've seen, it should automatically create a cookie when the grid is destroyed. Unfortunately, it's not doing that for me. I can manually create a cookie by calling Document.cookie = "key=value"; I've even tried calling the dojo.destroy method to force to write the code.

My application uses AMD to include the required libraries and I have separated most of my Javascript into a separate Javascript file including the code that creates my enhanced grid and sets up the plugins. Every other plugin is working as expected including the DnD, IndirectSelection, Menus, and Pagination. I'm stumped as to what to try next as there are not many forum posts of people having the same problem as me. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this is much appreciated.

Here's the code I use to create the grid.

```
    /* Begin Setting up table */
    var data = {
        identifier : "BARCODE", //This field needs to have unique values
        label : "BARCODE", //Name field for display. Not pertinent to a grid but may be used elsewhere.
        items : []
    };

    var store = dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data:data});

    /*set up the layout */
    var layout = [
        {name: 'File No', field: 'FILENUMBER', width: '125px'},
        {name: 'Pg No', field: 'SHEET_NUMBER'},
        {name: 'Pg Ttl', field: 'SHEET_TOTAL'},
        {name: 'Print Date', field: 'PRINT_DATE', width: '80px'},// formatter: formatDate},
        {name: 'Project Name', field: 'PROJECT_NAME', width: '400px'},
        {name: 'Barcode', field: 'BARCODE', width: '125px'},
        {name: 'Community', field: 'COMMUNITY', width: '125px'},
        {name: 'Title Block', field: 'TITLE_BLOCK'},
        {name: 'Com Date', field: 'ACCEPTANCE_DATE'},
        {name: 'Archive', field: 'ARCHIVE_DRAWER'},
        {name: 'Com No', field: 'INSTRUMENT_NUMBER'}
    ];
            /* create the new grid */
    var grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
        id: 'grid',
        store: store,
        structure: layout,
        rowSelector: '20px',
        plugins:{
            dnd: true,
            indirectSelection:{headerSelector:true, width:"40px", styles:"text-align:center;"},
            pagination: {
                pageSizes:["10", "25", "50", "All"],
                description: true,
                sizeSwitch: true,
                pageStepper: true,
                gotoButton: true,
                maxPageStep: 4,
                position: "top"
            },
            menus: menusObject,
            cookie: {
                columnOrder: true
            }
         } 
    },
    document.createElement('div'));

    /* append the grid to the div */
    dojo.byId("gridDiv").appendChild(grid.domNode);

    /* Call startup() to render the grid */
    grid.startup();
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to help us debugging ?

Comment: I tried doing that yesterday without any luck. My full application doesn't work including the part that loads the table.